# How to combine .tab.gz files into one gz file not repeating the colunm header?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I am currently using this simple `cat` to combine gzip tab-delimited files. However, since both have the same column header, I am ending up with one header at the beginning of the file and another header at the middle, where it was concatenated. How can I leave just one header for the `c.gz` file without having to decompress the files?

Example of the files:

a.tab

```
col1      col2      col3
1      2      3
```

b.tab

```
col1      col2      col3
1      4      6
```

desired c.tab

```
col1      col2      col3
1      2      3
1      4      6
```

What I am trying:  `cat a.tab.gz b.tab.gz > c.tab.gz`

What I am getting in the `c.tab`:

```
col1      col2      col3
1      2      3
col1      col2      col3
1      4      6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR>1||NR==1' <(gunzip -c a.tab.gz) <(gunzip -c b.tab.gz) | gzip > c.tab.gz
```

Output inside `c.tab.gz`:

```
col1      col2      col3
1      2      3
1      4      6
```

**Edit**: Another awk:

```
$ zcat [ab].tab.gz | awk 'NR==1{h=$0;print}$0!=h' | gzip > c.tab.gz
```

which excludes the records which are identical to the first record of the first file uncompressed - which might cause problems if you have headers in the data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It works!
I'm really a noob in the command line, so how can I ```cat``` the results to a new tab compressed file called ```c.tab.gz```, for example?

Comment: Updated the solution. Sorry, missed that the first time.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to zcat the files. You have uncompressed the files and that was not what was initially requested?

Comment: @RamanSailopal _You have uncompressed the files_ What do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

```
(zcat a.tab.gz;awk 'NR>1 { print }' <(zcat b.tab.gz)) | gzip > c.tab.gz
```

Cat the contents of a.tab.gz with zcat and then redirect the output of zcat b.tab.gz back into awk, printing everything apart from the first line. Pipe the combined output to gzip wand the file c.tab.gz

Same solution with sed processing headers:

```
(zcat a.tab.gz;sed -n '2,$p' <(zcat b.tab.gz)) | gzip > c.tab.gz
```

Comment: For some reason the ```(zcat a.tab.gz;awk 'NR>1 { print }' <(zcat b.tab.gz)) | gzip > c.tab.gz``` does not work. ```zcat: can't stat: No such file or directory
```. I am sure the file is there and it's written correctly though. The solution from james worked, but it takes some time for my huge files. Same error for the second solution as well.